# ExtJS MVC - How to integrate html files that has been constructed using MVC pattern based on different modules into one html file?

Tags: html, json, extjs, extjs-mvc

I'm currently working on a ExtJS Project where I have constructed my HTML files based on three modules.

```
1. Login Module - Login Page,
2. Teacher Module - Teacher Home Page,
3. Student Module - Student Home Page.
```

My File structure is given below:

```
SAR
-student.html,
-teacher.html,
-login.html and their respective main js files in this SAR folder
```

inside an app folder  under SAR, I have all my controllers, views, data, stores, models.

I need to integrate all the three html into one to avoid loading of extjs file thrice. MVC pattern is really confusing. When I integrate some of my functions are not working.

login.html has:

```
    <div id="login-Container"></div>

    <div id="teacherContainer">
        <div id="teacherHome"></div>
        <div id="teacherHomeChart"></div>
    </div>


    <div id="studentContainer">
        <div id="studentHome"></div>
        <div id="studentHomeChart"></div>
    </div>
```

login page controller ->

```
// JavaScript Document

Ext.define('nSpace.controller.studentAssessmentController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: [
        'Users'
    ],
    views: [
        'login.loginView'
    ],
    model: 'loginModel',
    init: function() {      
        this.control({
            "#loginButton": {
                click: this.onLoginButtonClick              
            }
        });
    },
    onLoginButtonClick: function(){
       //Unable to GET HERE
        alert('hi')
                var store = this.getUsersStore();
                var logUserName = Ext.getCmp('UserName').getValue();    
                var logPassword = Ext.getCmp('Password').getValue();
                //console.log(store.data.items[0].data.loginusername)
                //console.log(store.data.items.length)
                for (var i=0;i<store.data.items.length;i++)
                {
                if(i+1 == store.data.items.length)
                {
                alert('Please check your username and password.')   
                }   
                else if (logUserName === store.data.items[i].data.loginusername  && logPassword === store.data.items[i].data.password)
                {
                    if(logUserName.indexOf("student") != -1)
                    {
                        alert('Student');

                        //var element = Ext.get('teacherContainer');
                        //element.hide();
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(logUserName.indexOf("teacher" != -1))
                    {
                        alert('Teacher');
                        break;
                    }                           
                }
                }

    }
});
```

app.js->

```
// JavaScript Document
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ 
 enabled: true
 });
Ext.application({
    requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
    name: 'nSpace',
    controllers: [
        'studentAssessmentController'
    ],
    appFolder: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
                    renderTo: 'login-Container',
                    items: {
                        cls: 'loginView',
                        xtype: 'loginView'
                    }
                   });
       /* Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {       

        });*/
    }
});
```

I got all the views on my page correctly with the functionalities also but, my onLoginButtonClick is not triggering to show and hide respective div's(teacher & student module div's on their respective login). Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Or if someone could tell me what should be done for a neat integration, that would help.

Comment: Are you sure your js code is syntactically correct? I see ; and ) missing here or there. Incorrect code won't run. Do you use any js debugger to help with finding any hidden errors? Most of the modern browser have some debugger built-in or a plug-in to install.

Comment: Yes. I do use Chrome latest version. I do not see any kind of syntax errors when I run my file. Its working fine. But the code doesn't go to my controller.

Answer (score 0):

In login Controller right declaration of view is :

```
views: [
    'loginView'
],
```